# How to minimize some of the stats in your script UI - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am searching in google for my problem, but it is hard to find any information on the web when you don't know the exact word for it.

I saw this in a video and I really would like to know how can I do that. You can see a screenshot below about it:

[image: image for explaination]

If anyone knows the name of it or how to do it, i would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: You mean expandable element? Something like in [this example](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html)

Comment: Yes Thanks for the info m8 now i know what to google. may you have a nice day.

Comment: You can also write [custom inspector scripts](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector) to do some of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same visual as I stated in comment ( expandable element ) you need to either create your own `EditorScript` or use smaller data models.

---

Example usage of data models:

Let's say you want to display player's statistics inside of that expandable element, all you have to do is to create a `class` for that element ( `PlayerStatistics` and mark it with `Serializable` attribute:

```
[Serializable]
public class PlayerStatistics
{
    public float Health;
}
```

Now in your `MonoBehaviour` add this as a member field :

```
public class MeBehaviour
    : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerStatistics PlayerStats;
}
```

Default editor behavior should automatically wrap `PlayerStatistics` inside an expandable element.

---

Another way is to use an array or `List<>` that will do basically the same.